# Android Image doesn't save using native camera app on Nexus S

Tags: android, camera, nexus-s

So this is kind of weird because out of the three devices I'm testing on, I only get this issue on the Google Nexus S with 4.0.3. I'm starting the native camera app to take a picture, and I don't care where the image is saved to, so I don't specify, hoping that it will get saved to the default location, but no location is saved at all!

Does work fine on the Galaxy S 2 and Samsung Skyrocket (both with 2.3.something).

Code I'm using to start the app

```
Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camIntent, TAKE_PHOTO);
return true;
```

I'm keeping it really simple, that's why I'm confused! Does anyone know of any issues specific to the Nexus S's camera?

**EDIT:** It would seem that maybe the Nexus S's camera app saves the file in some onActivityResult, and since I start up the native camera app and don't save the image upon return, it doesn't save it. Does anyone know this this to be true? Seen this behavior?

**EDIT:** No one has seen this? I find it hard to believe I'm the first person to run into this...

**EDIT:** Alright, well after working on it some more, I tried adding a URI into the EXTRA_OUTPUT of the intent like so:

```
camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.parse(folderPath + String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

And now I see the behavior described here: [Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent) where the camera app doesn't do anything when I hit ok, and creating the file beforehand doesn't work either, as I tried like this:

```
File f = new File(folderPath, filename);
f.createNewFile();
camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.parse(folderPath + filename));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277287/default-camera-activity-not-finishing-upon-ok-button-press/14806908#14806908

Just check the above..might be helpful...The issue might be because of file name or path(which would be better if it has no special characters like spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, figured it out. Oddly, and I have NO idea why, but changing this line:

```
camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.parse(folderPath + filename));
```

to

```
camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
```

fixed it. Don't know if I should understand why... but whatever, it works. I did try a billion other things...

not specifying an EXTRA_OUTPUT at all -> camera would act like everything was good... except it wouldn't save the image ANYWHERE

getting the bitmap taken by intent.getExtras().get("data") -> did return a bitmap, but it was not the full size image as documented extensively in many bug reports

using the above Uri.parse method -> causes the native camera app checkmark button to not do anything when clicked

Hope this helps someone..